# How do I remove textarea content indentation in jade?

Tags: pug

If I have a textarea, how do I remove the indentation required by Jade?

Example of what I want to achieve in regular HTML (the empty divs are to simulate a "real" markup simulation where you have indents):

http://codepen.io/wolfr/pen/pgjzKa

```
<div>
    <div>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="100">
We had an incident yesterday at the Evansville shop. John fell from the truck the other day.

After we reviewed the issue we found out he didn't have three points of contact at all times.

We want to make sure everyone is on board with the procedure. Please follow the procedures and refer to the employee handbook in attachment.
      </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example of how far I got in Jade:
http://codepen.io/wolfr/pen/rxOBrq?editors=100

```
div
    div
        textarea(rows="20", cols="100")
            | We had an incident yesterday at the Evansville shop. John fell from the truck the other day.
            |
            | After we reviewed the issue we found out he didn't have three points of contact at all times.
            |
            | We want to make sure everyone is on board with the procedure. Please follow the procedures and refer to the employee handbook in attachment.
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just a FYI that you don't need commas between attributes in Jade. You used to, but not anymore since about a year now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution I can think of:

```
div
    div
        - text = "We had an incident yesterday at the Evansville shop. " +
        -   "John fell from the truck the other day.\n\n" +
        -   "After we reviewed the issue we found out he didn't " +
        -   "have three points of contact at all times.\n\n" +
        -   "We want to make sure everyone is on board with the procedure. " +
        -   "Please follow the procedures and refer to the employee handbook in attachment."

        textarea(rows="20", cols="100")
           != text
```

Comment: Using this solution gives me an "SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant".Oddly enough this solution works on Codepen but not locally: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbOBWB?editors=100

Comment: Hmm indeed, just tried it too. Putting it all on one line like you did seems to work though.

Comment: It was an issue where we were also beautifying the HTML after processing the jade. So that's why it didn't work on our end but did work on Codepen. Jade, I love you but hate you :D Thanks for your input.